# python beatifulsoup webscrape different elements in a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping

there is loop in a table i want to scrape

```
<ul>
<li class="cell036 tal arrow"><a href=" y/">ALdCTL</a></li>
<li class="cell009">5,71</li>
<li class="cell009">5,74</li>   
<li class="cell009">-3,04</li>   
<li class="cell009">5,92</li>   
<li class="cell009">5,76</li>   
<li class="cell009">5,53</li>   
<li class="cell009">907.438</li>   
<li class="cell009">5.114.192</li> 
</ul>
```

my python code works of on finding  text inside `a` but not text inside the first element of `li` class `cell009`

```
c=soup.findAll('li',class_='cell036 tal arrow' )

for foo in soup.find_all('li', class_= ['cell036 tal arrow']):

   bar = foo.find(['a'])
   print(bar.text)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please revise your question so that it is more clear.

Comment: i want to find  this> inside a > ALdCTL and values next to that xx xx xx so the result,,,,  ALdCTL xx xx xx xx xx

Comment: currently i can only pull names

Answer (score 1):

To scrape all values, you just need to get all the `li` tags (without restraining the search to the element with class `cell036 tal arrow` which is why you only get that value):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """
<ul>
<li class="cell036 tal arrow"><a href=" y/">ALdCTL</a></li>
<li class="cell009">5,71</li>
<li class="cell009">5,74</li>
<li class="cell009">-3,04</li>
<li class="cell009">5,92</li>
<li class="cell009">5,76</li>
<li class="cell009">5,53</li>
<li class="cell009">907.438</li>
<li class="cell009">5.114.192</li>
</ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

for foo in soup.find_all('li'):

   print(foo.text)
```

Outputs:

```
ALdCTL
5,71
5,74
-3,04
5,92
5,76
5,53
907.438
5.114.192
```

Comment: + and hope you don't mind my borrowing your opening lines.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing drec4s opening structure you might be able to use a CSS Or combination as well to target the li elements by class name.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """
<ul>
<li class="cell036 tal arrow"><a href=" y/">ALdCTL</a></li>
<li class="cell009">5,71</li>
<li class="cell009">5,74</li>
<li class="cell009">-3,04</li>
<li class="cell009">5,92</li>
<li class="cell009">5,76</li>
<li class="cell009">5,53</li>
<li class="cell009">907.438</li>
<li class="cell009">5.114.192</li>
</ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

for foo in soup.select('li.cell036.tal.arrow,li.cell009'):

   print(foo.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other `li` elements are not contained *inside* the `li` you're looking into. They are *siblings*. Use [`find_next_siblings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
content = """
<ul>
<li class="cell036 tal arrow"><a href=" y/">ALdCTL</a></li>
<li class="cell009">5,71</li>
<li class="cell009">5,74</li>   
<li class="cell009">-3,04</li>   
<li class="cell009">5,92</li>   
<li class="cell009">5,76</li>   
<li class="cell009">5,53</li>   
<li class="cell009">907.438</li>   
<li class="cell009">5.114.192</li> 
</ul>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content)
header = soup.findAll("li", class_="cell036 tal arrow")

header[0].find_next_siblings("li")
```

Gives:

```
[<li class="cell009">5,71</li>,
 <li class="cell009">5,74</li>,
 <li class="cell009">-3,04</li>,
 <li class="cell009">5,92</li>,
 <li class="cell009">5,76</li>,
 <li class="cell009">5,53</li>,
 <li class="cell009">907.438</li>,
 <li class="cell009">5.114.192</li>]
```